# In Playwright, Cucumber feature files not being recognised from index.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, cucumber, babeljs, playwright

In my Playwright test, I am trying to run a cucumber feature using `npm run cucumber --profile dev`, however no scenarios are being picked up:

[image: consoleMessage]

Here is my `index.ts` file:

```
const common = `./src/features/**/*.feature \
                --require-module ts-node/register \
                --require ./src/step-definitions/**/**/*.ts \
                -f json:./reports/report.json \
                --format progress-bar `;

const dev = `${common} --tags '@dev'`;
const smoke = `${common} --tags '@smoke'`;
const regression = `${common} --tags '@regression'`;

export { dev, smoke, regression }
```

And here is my folder structure as that may be useful:

[image: projectFolderStructure]

Also, my `home-page.feature` file:

```
Feature: As a user I expect to be able to navigate to the home page

    @dev
    @regression
    Scenario: As a user I expect to be able to see contacts
        Given I am on the 'home' page
         Then the 'contacts header' should contain the text 'Contacts'
```

And my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "personalised-offers-platform-e2e-pw",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "transpile": "rimraf dist && babel --extensions .ts --out-dir dist src",
    "cucumber": "npm run transpile && cucumber-js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.5.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.23.4",
    "playwright": "^1.23.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

I have tried running just `npm run cucumber` to see if the tags were the issue, but it gives the same output as above.

Originally, I thought the problem was with the `common` paths in my `index.ts`, as the feature wasn't being picked up, but they look OK to me now.

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong, & how I can fix it?

I can provide further code to help shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "cucumber" option `-p` or `--profile`:

```
npm run transpile && cucumber-js -p
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run using the following command

```
npm run cucumber -- --profile dev
```